# Position inline span tags within a div ancestor

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="widget-header">
    <span class="widget-title">
        Widget 1
    </span>
    <span class="widget-menu">
        <span class="btn change-col">
           To Main
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Given the html above, I'd like to have `span.widget-title` and `span.widget-menu` inline with `widget-title` left-justified and `widget-menu` right justified. Currently, I have the following css:

```
.widget-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.widget-title { 
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.widget-menu {  
    width: 50%;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;*/
}
```

Notice the commented out part of .widget-menu. If I enable that, then the view "flips out" and the widget-header disappears completely. Why is that happening, and what's the best way to position these tags so that the style is maintainable and capable of accommodating future changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'flip out' happens because the parent div has no width or height because its span childrens have position absolute. To fix this you can give the div a fixed height

```
.widget-header{ 
    height:50px; 
    width:500px; 
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dGrLh/2/

Or float the spans instead of position absolute like:

```
.widget-title { 
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
}

.widget-menu { 
    float:right;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dGrLh/1/

Comment: That did it! I went with the second one, but which one do you think is better? Also, why does overflow: hidden solve the widget-header disappearing?

Comment: @Vish Deciding which solution is better strongly depends on the context you are using it, that is your website layout. The overflow property makes the parent expand to contain their children elements, there is a more in-deph explanation about floats here: http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/